# How to allow all Network connection types HTTP and HTTPS in Android (9) Pie?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-9.0-pie, android-network-security-config

From Android 9 Pie now, requests without encryption will never work. And by default, the System will expect you to use TLS by default.[You can read this feature here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/08/introducing-android-9-pie.html) So if you only make requests via HTTPS you are safe. But what about apps that make requests through different sites, for instance, browser-like apps.

How can I enable requests to all types of connections HTTP and HTTPS in Android 9 Pie?

Answer (score 424, accepted):

The easy way to implement this is to use this attribute to your `AndroidManifest.xml` where you allow all `http` for all requests:

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
</application>
```

But in case you want some **more configurations** for different links for instance, allowing `http` for some domains but not other domains you must provide `res/xml/networkSecurityConfig.xml` file.

To do this in Android 9 Pie you will have to set a `networkSecurityConfig` in your Manifest `application` tag like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">




    </application>
</manifest>
```

Then in your `xml` folder you now have to create a file named `network_security_config` just like the way you have named it in the Manifest and from there the content of your file should be like this to enable all requests without encryptions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

From there you are good to go. Now your app will make requests for all types of connections. For additional information on this topic [read here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config).

Comment: @Xenolion After I made these changes (with a React Native application) it no longer builds. "Manifest merger not successful". "Attribute application@networkSecurityConfig value=(@xml/react_native_config) from AndroidManifest.xml:7:7-67 is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:7:7-67 value=(@xml/network_security_config). Any  ideas?

Comment: @Wyatt im having same issue as you, did you find any solution?

Comment: @DanteCervantes check out my answer above.

Comment: is the app down listed in the PlayStore if we use the "android:usesCleartextTraffic="true". I know that for the Google Search Engine, it can affect your rank if your website does not provide https access.

Comment: Where can i find the xml folder in react native project

Comment: Waste plenty of time figuring out this is actually HTTP issue. normally it shows ERROR on HTTP RESPONSE

Comment: Just add the first statement `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in your Android Manifest for React Native. @CraZyDroiD

Comment: This is not working in case of opening third party link inside webview. Please help

Comment: It doest work on api below 23 , not working on lollipop or below device

Comment: AndroidManifest and network_security_config files are located in React native at 
`android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`
`android/app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml`

Answer (score 56):

The **FULLY WORKING SOLUTION** for both **`Android`** or **`React-native`** users facing this issue just add this 
`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`
 in **AndroidManifest.xml** file like this:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
<uses-library
    android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
    android:required="false" />
```

in between `<application>`.. `</application>` tag like this:

```
<application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <uses-library
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" />
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"/>
 </application>
```

Comment: Wow thanks its working fine in my app ,before its showing i/o failure issue now solved

Comment: if you get `tools:ignore` error, make sure to add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` inside your `application`. Like so `<application xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" ...`

Comment: I know this is an android question but might help for react-native developers, the ios solution is to add `NSAppTransportSecurity` to info.plist. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38418998/react-native-fetch-network-request-failed

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal I am still unable to download pdf file (having http url) in React Native App. Though, `https url` are working fine. I have tried adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` and `uses-library` part, but still no luck :(

Comment: @NarendraSingh try to check whether the pdf url is valid or not and also use react-native-fs to access the file system of app to download the pdf.

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal Yes, pdf url is valid, I tried with various urls to ensure that. Also, I tried a few other methods and libs including `Linking` and `react-native-file-download`, but none of them worked for https url.

Comment: @NarendraSingh which version are you using of react native?

Comment: @NarendraSingh check whether it is related to Flipper issue in react native.

Answer (score 27):

A simple way is set `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` on you `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Your `AndroidManifest.xml` look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.dww.drmanar">
   <application
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
       tools:targetApi="m">
       <activity
            android:name=".activity.SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
       </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I had the same issue on 14th May 2021, with the help of @Mehul Solanki. The problem got fixed.

Answer (score 19):

**Easy Way**

Add `usesCleartextTraffic` to **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application
...
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
...>
```

Indicates whether the app intends to use cleartext network traffic, such as cleartext HTTP. The default value for apps that target API **level 27** or lower is "true". Apps that target API **level 28** or higher default to "false".

Comment: Yes easy, but this is the least safe solution.

Answer (score 14):

For `React Native` applications while running in debug add the `xml block` mentioned by @Xenolion to `react_native_config.xml` located in `<project>/android/app/src/debug/res/xml`

Similar to the following snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="false">localhost</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="false">10.0.2.2</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="false">10.0.3.2</domain>
    </domain-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: It throws exception on flutter ```E/flutter (19798): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(209)] Dart Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument (domain): Invalid domain name: "localhost", stack trace: #0      new _DomainNetworkPolicy (dart:io/network_policy.dart:85:7)```

Comment: It's working for me now Thanks ...BTW I'm using React Natice

Comment: This worked for me w/ React Native 60.6, Android 10, Gradle 3.4.3... if running in emulator and you still have issues with connecting to packaging server, try `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` in your terminal (assuming 8081 is the port metro bundler is running on)

Answer (score 11):

Just set `usesCleartextTraffic` flag in the application tag of `AndroidManifest.xml` file.
No need to create config file for Android.

```
 <application
   android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
   .
   .
   .>
```

Answer (score 4):

i got the same problem and i notice that my security config has diferent TAGS like the @Xenolion answer says

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

so i change the TAGS "domain-config" for "base-config" and works, like this:

```
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: can you please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59116787/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-cleartext-not-permitted

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me,

add this xml file to:
**andriod/app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml**

**network_security_config.xml**

```
xml/network_security_config.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">your_domain1</domain>
    </domain-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">your_domain2</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

then add this code to **AndroidMenifest.xml**

```
<application
    ...
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    ...
      >
      <!-- for http support-->
      <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
      ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add usesCleartextTraffic to AndroidManifest.xml

e.g.

```
<application
...
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
...>
```

in

```
<application
    android: allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="AndroidLearning"
    android: supportsRtl="true"
    android:UsesCleartextTraffic="true" <-----
    android: theme="@style/Theme.AndroidLearning"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
    android:name=" MainActivity"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android. intent.action.MAIN" />
    ‹catedorv android:name="android.intent.catedorv.LAUNCHFR" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You may check if you are sending clearText through HTTP
Fix : https://medium.com/@son.rommer/fix-cleartext-traffic-error-in-android-9-pie-2f4e9e2235e6
 
 OR 
In the Case of  Apache HTTP client deprecation  (From Google ) :
With Android 6.0, we removed support for the Apache HTTP client. Beginning with Android 9, that library is removed from the bootclasspath and is not available to apps by default.
To continue using the Apache HTTP client, apps that target Android 9 and above can add the following to their AndroidManifest.xml:

Source 
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28

Answer (score 0):

## For Android 14, I solved the issue only with dart

> ###### The idea is to override the HTTP Security Context for the entire application.

Step 1: implement `CustomHttpOverrides` class which extend the default dart `HttpOverrides` class

```
import 'dart:io';

// extend `HttpOverrides` class
class CustomHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? securityContext){
    return super
        .createHttpClient(securityContext)
        ..badCertificateCallback =
                        (X509Certificate certificate, String hostName, int hostPort)=> true;
  }
}
```

Step 2: Override the default dart `HttpOverrides` class with the `CustomHttpOverrides` in the `main()` method within the `main.dart` file

```
void main() {
  HttpOverrides.global = CustomHttpOverrides();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Use cases:
In the Android Emulator you can access your services / API's running on your local machine via http and https protocols simply by send the http requests to `10.0.2.2` just like:

> `http://10.0.2.2:<port>/endpoint`

> `https://10.0.2.2:<port>/endpoint`

### practice example

I have a web API implemented with C#, .NET 8 running on local machine with this http launch settings:

[image]

For https requests I have the port **1000** and for http requests I have the port **5197**

To be able to send http requests to my API endpoints, I have temporarily disabled the Https Redirection:

`// app.UseHttpsRedirection();`

To fetch data from the Android Emulator, I attempted to send requests from Chrome to my endpoint:

- Using HTTP: `http://10.0.2.2:5197/contracts/retrieve-contracts`

[image]

[image]

- Using HTTPS: `https://10.0.2.2:1000/contracts/retrieve-contracts`

To send the http requests from a Flutter application:

```
// HTTP request
Response responseViaHttp = 
http.get(Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:5197/contracts/retrieve-contracts'))
as http.Response;

// HTTPS request
Response responseViaHttps =
http.get(Uri.parse('https://10.0.2.2:1000/contracts/retrieve-contracts'))
as http.Response;
```

### Useful links:

[HttpOverrides class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/HttpOverrides-class.html)

[SecurityContext class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/SecurityContext-class.html)

[Android Emulator networking](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking)