# How to add includeSubdomains dynamically in network-security-config.xml file Android

Tags: android

I wanna add multiple domains in network_security_config.xml file at runtime, how can i achieve that? This is the content of network_security_config.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">api.example.com</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">assets.example.com</domain>
    </domain-config>

    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false" />
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: You can refer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie