# HttpUrlConnection connect() method returns IOException, only from android 9 (pie)

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection, urlconnection, android-9.0-pie

In my android app I have a method that checks connection with server by url.
It is working great, but only on devices with oreo and below. From android 9 getResponseCode() method from HttpUrlConnection always returns IOException.
Logcat also shows a warn, to the line of code with urlc.connect();

> W/System.err: at pl.wrestleone.goodwrestleone.MainActivity.isURLReachable(MainActivity.java:290)

How can I repair this strange method behavior? Thanks for any help.

```
static public boolean isURLReachable(Context context, String webUrl) {

    ConnectivityManager cm;
    cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(webUrl);   // Change to "http://google.com" for www  test.
            HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlc.setConnectTimeout(10 * 1000);          // 10 s.
            urlc.connect();
            if (urlc.getResponseCode() == 200) {        // 200 = "OK" code (http connection is fine).
                return true;

            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Share the actual IOException that is thrown. You can derive the reason in the exception message.

Comment: use `HTTPS` or add a network security configuration.

Comment: You were right. Network security configuration solved this problem. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie) was very helpful.

Comment: [This](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) also.