# Android App on API 28 (Pie) devices returns i/o exception while attempting connect to Parse Server on AWS

Tags: android, api, parse-platform, ioexception, parse-android-sdk

I have developed android application which uses Parse Server on AWS as back end.
Application has login and data browsing capabilities.
Everything is working smooth on all devices with API lower than 28.
When I updated my Galaxy S9 plus to Android Pie, my app stopped working.
It returns toast saying "i/o exception" and not much information in console I could work with.
Gradle file is also updated to support android Pie devices.
All network related permissions in Manifest file are added.
Is very frustrating when I can't use my own app just because I have latest firmware update.

Does anyone have experienced similar issue? Is there anything different in permissions for API 28?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the configure your app part from the above answer, use the top answer from here for your purposes 
[How to allow all Network connection types HTTP and HTTPS in Android (9) Pie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie)

Comment: maybe you can accept this answer then :D. Would be help to anyone who's unfortunate enough to wander here

Answer (score 0):

There are some networking changes in Android Pie that you will want to be aware of - more information can be found here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all#device-security-changes

I would make sure that you are not doing networking on the main thread, you are using https requests (if you need an ssl cert checkout Let's Encrypt) or configure your app to use non https urls.

I recommend reading https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-migration to help with troubleshooting Android Pie issues.