# HttpURLConnection with JSON on Android 9, API 28

Tags: java, android, json, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to use HttpURLConnection in Android 9, API 28. It works on Android 8.0.0, API 26, but not on API 28.

```
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.accumulate("name", name);
            String json = jsonObject.toString();

            URL url = new URL("http://website_link");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");

            OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            os.close();

            InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("utf-8")), 8);
            String line;
            json = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                json += line;
            }

            inputStream.close();

            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);

            inputStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();

            ...
```

I tried to use `Log.d` to see what code is not executed and I saw that it stops on `OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();`

Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: How is this "not working"? Crash? Unexpected behavior?

Comment: As I wrote it stops on OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();. That part is not executed and nothing happens, app doesn't crash, just that part is not executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this add `Manifest.xml`

```
cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"
```

it look like this
[How to allow all Network connection types HTTP and HTTPS in Android (9) Pie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie)

Comment: Thank you, I added android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in application tag inside AndroidManifest.xml and it works!

Comment: i have error with importing these library how to resolve this HTTPurlConnection not found

Answer (score 0):

This is because of Apache HTTP client depreciation ,
So add the below line in 
 tag.

```
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

Comment: I tried to add that tag and it didn't worked. Solution by Hasan Kucuk to add cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" worked.