# How to run an application on real mobile phone rather than using the emulator?

Tags: android, xampp, android-volley, ipv6, sslhandshakeexception

I am new to android application development, when I try to run my server(using **Xampp**) the app works fine on my **emulator,** However after changing http://10.0.2.2 to my local ip using(**IPv 4**), the app which is user registration does not work when attempting to test it **on my real mobile device** (oneplus 6t) which uses android pie since this **error** is shown when attempting to create a new account :

**Register Error!
com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.**"

I believe that this error has something to due with my ip address because when I try to open the server using my ip the following alert is shown in google chrome

**"** Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from my *ip-address* (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID **"**[image]

Comment: Related: https://www.blog.google/products/chrome/milestone-chrome-security-marking-http-not-secure/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android 9, you need to have secure https connections, that's the error that is returning to you

Is the same error you are having in chrome

Comment: Any suggestions on how to make secure https connections?

Comment: @jesmar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie this is how to make any type of connection in android 9 

To have secure https connections you need a SSL certificate installed on your website

Comment: I have tried that solution but still did not work ...if I test it using a mobile phone that does not involve android pie it should work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this add manifest

cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"

[How to allow all Network connection types HTTP and HTTPS in Android (9) Pie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie)

Comment: Yes I am working using android pie device is this issue on available to android pie??

Comment: added the following in my manifest and error still occuring         android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Comment: @jesmar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie

Comment: I have tried that suggestion and still the same error :(