# React Native Fetch Not Working on Android

Tags: android, react-native

```
fetch("http://httpbin.org/post")
   .then(response => response.json())
   .then(responseData => {})
   .catch(error => {
   Alert.alert("error:" + error);
});
```

I am trying to get fetches to work on Android. The sample code above get's called, however, it alerts "error:TypeError: Network request failed".

I have the INTERNET permission set in my Android manifest file. Not really sure what else to do. Is there a way I can find out the reason for the error?

**EDIT**
When debugging, status is 0, timeout is 0, response is null, responseURL is undefined, and responseType is blob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http is your issue ... https is needed

Comment: My PHP pages don't work with HTTPS for some reason. Is there any way I could get HTTP working?

Comment: check out this stackoverflow post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie

Comment: I don't have an XML folder in my project. Do I need to create one, and where must it be created?

Comment: C:\Users\USER\TestProject\android\app\src\debug\res

Comment: Found it in there. Thanks for your help

Comment: Hmm, my Android build is failing now after the manifest changes. "Execution failed for task ':app:processsDebugManifest'. Manifest merger failed" It also suggests adding 'tools:replace="android:networkSecurityConfig"' to <application>. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to Manifest file solved my issue in Android 9

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">



    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28" />
```

Comment: Yes add in /android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml