# Android app not launching on Android 9 versions

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-build

I have a react native project for android app, when I build the apk and tested on a real device, it works on most of the devices except Android 9

I tried to comment on this abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86" with no luck

the is installed on Android Pie, but it does not load any data it shows only the first window, and it works on the lower versions perfectly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJeVi.jpg)
here is the debug log

```
2019-04-20 18:53:15.507 10428-10428/? I/com.beonews: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2019-04-20 18:53:15.526 10428-10428/? W/com.beonews: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2019-04-20 18:53:16.085 10428-10428/com.beonews W/com.beonews: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
2019-04-20 18:53:16.089 10428-10428/com.beonews I/chatty: uid=10087(com.beonews) identical 10 lines
2019-04-20 18:53:16.090 10428-10428/com.beonews W/com.beonews: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
2019-04-20 18:53:18.324 10428-10428/com.beonews I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
2019-04-20 18:53:18.327 10428-10428/com.beonews I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
2019-04-20 18:53:18.385 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: init start
2019-04-20 18:53:18.385 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: adding system library source: /vendor/lib
2019-04-20 18:53:18.385 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: adding system library source: /system/lib
2019-04-20 18:53:18.386 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: adding application source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/com.beonews-RuQNHa98khpLrWL4ziWd4A==/lib/x86 flags = 0]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.387 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: adding backup source from : com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-main flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.387 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: adding backup sources from split apks
2019-04-20 18:53:18.387 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: adding backup source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-0 flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.387 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: adding backup source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-1 flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.387 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: adding backup source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-2 flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.388 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: adding backup source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-3 flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.388 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: adding backup source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-4 flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.388 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: adding backup source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-5 flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.388 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: adding backup source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-6 flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.388 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: adding backup source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-7 flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.388 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: adding backup source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-8 flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.389 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: adding backup source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-9 flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.389 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: adding backup source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-10 flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.389 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: adding backup source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-11 flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.389 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /system/lib flags = 2]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.389 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /vendor/lib flags = 2]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.389 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.DirectorySoSource[root = /data/app/com.beonews-RuQNHa98khpLrWL4ziWd4A==/lib/x86 flags = 0]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.389 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-11 flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.391 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-11
2019-04-20 18:53:18.393 10428-10428/com.beonews I/fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-11
2019-04-20 18:53:18.393 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-11
2019-04-20 18:53:18.393 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-10 flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.394 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-10
2019-04-20 18:53:18.395 10428-10445/com.beonews D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2019-04-20 18:53:18.399 10428-10428/com.beonews I/fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-10
2019-04-20 18:53:18.399 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-10
2019-04-20 18:53:18.400 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-9 flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.400 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-9
2019-04-20 18:53:18.403 10428-10428/com.beonews I/fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-9
2019-04-20 18:53:18.403 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-9
2019-04-20 18:53:18.403 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-8 flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.404 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-8
2019-04-20 18:53:18.405 10428-10428/com.beonews I/fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-8
2019-04-20 18:53:18.405 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-8
2019-04-20 18:53:18.405 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-7 flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.405 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-7
2019-04-20 18:53:18.408 10428-10428/com.beonews I/fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-7
2019-04-20 18:53:18.408 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-7
2019-04-20 18:53:18.409 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-6 flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.409 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-6
2019-04-20 18:53:18.410 10428-10428/com.beonews I/fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-6
2019-04-20 18:53:18.410 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-6
2019-04-20 18:53:18.410 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-5 flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.410 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-5
2019-04-20 18:53:18.412 10428-10428/com.beonews I/fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-5
2019-04-20 18:53:18.412 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-5
2019-04-20 18:53:18.412 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-4 flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.413 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-4
2019-04-20 18:53:18.414 10428-10428/com.beonews I/fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-4
2019-04-20 18:53:18.414 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-4
2019-04-20 18:53:18.414 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-3 flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.415 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-3
2019-04-20 18:53:18.417 10428-10428/com.beonews I/fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-3
2019-04-20 18:53:18.417 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-3
2019-04-20 18:53:18.417 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-2 flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.418 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-2
2019-04-20 18:53:18.419 10428-10428/com.beonews I/fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-2
2019-04-20 18:53:18.419 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-2
2019-04-20 18:53:18.419 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-1 flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.419 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-1
2019-04-20 18:53:18.420 10428-10428/com.beonews I/fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-1
2019-04-20 18:53:18.420 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-1
2019-04-20 18:53:18.420 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-0 flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.420 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-0
2019-04-20 18:53:18.421 10428-10428/com.beonews I/fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-0
2019-04-20 18:53:18.422 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-0
2019-04-20 18:53:18.422 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: Preparing SO source: com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource[root = /data/data/com.beonews/lib-main flags = 1]
2019-04-20 18:53:18.422 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-main
2019-04-20 18:53:18.426 10428-10428/com.beonews I/fb-UnpackingSoSource: dso store is up-to-date: /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-main
2019-04-20 18:53:18.426 10428-10428/com.beonews V/fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.beonews/lib-main
2019-04-20 18:53:18.427 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: init finish: 16 SO sources prepared
2019-04-20 18:53:18.427 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: init exiting
2019-04-20 18:53:18.793 10428-10428/com.beonews W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@8e994e4
2019-04-20 18:53:18.832 10428-10428/com.beonews D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
2019-04-20 18:53:18.832 10428-10428/com.beonews D/SoLoader: init exiting
2019-04-20 18:53:18.848 10428-10428/com.beonews W/com.beonews: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (light greylist, reflection)
2019-04-20 18:53:18.848 10428-10428/com.beonews W/com.beonews: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-04-20 18:53:18.848 10428-10428/com.beonews W/com.beonews: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-04-20 18:53:18.864 10428-10428/com.beonews D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
2019-04-20 18:53:18.864 10428-10428/com.beonews D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
2019-04-20 18:53:18.891 10428-10465/com.beonews W/unknown:ReconnectingWebSocket: Couldn't connect to "ws://10.0.2.2:8081/message?device=Android%20SDK%20built%20for%20x86%20-%209%20-%20API%2028&app=com.beonews&clientid=DevSupportManagerImpl", will silently retry
2019-04-20 18:53:18.891 10428-10464/com.beonews W/unknown:InspectorPackagerConnection: Couldn't connect to packager, will silently retry
2019-04-20 18:53:18.893 10428-10463/com.beonews W/unknown:ReactNative: The packager does not seem to be running as we got an IOException requesting its status: CLEARTEXT communication to 10.0.2.2 not permitted by network security policy
2019-04-20 18:53:18.899 10428-10428/com.beonews W/com.beonews: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2019-04-20 18:53:18.900 10428-10428/com.beonews W/com.beonews: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-04-20 18:53:18.908 10428-10428/com.beonews D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2019-04-20 18:53:18.920 10428-10428/com.beonews D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundFromBundleLoader()
2019-04-20 18:53:18.920 10428-10428/com.beonews D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
2019-04-20 18:53:18.920 10428-10428/com.beonews D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
2019-04-20 18:53:18.922 10428-10428/com.beonews W/unknown:ReactNative: Packager connection already open, nooping.
2019-04-20 18:53:18.922 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: About to load: libreactnativejni.so
2019-04-20 18:53:18.923 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-main
2019-04-20 18:53:18.923 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-0
2019-04-20 18:53:18.923 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-1
2019-04-20 18:53:18.923 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-2
2019-04-20 18:53:18.923 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-3
2019-04-20 18:53:18.923 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-4
2019-04-20 18:53:18.923 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-5
2019-04-20 18:53:18.924 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-6
2019-04-20 18:53:18.924 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-7
2019-04-20 18:53:18.924 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-8
2019-04-20 18:53:18.924 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-9
2019-04-20 18:53:18.924 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-10
2019-04-20 18:53:18.924 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-11
2019-04-20 18:53:18.924 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libreactnativejni.so found on /data/app/com.beonews-RuQNHa98khpLrWL4ziWd4A==/lib/x86
2019-04-20 18:53:18.924 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: Not resolving dependencies for libreactnativejni.so
2019-04-20 18:53:18.969 10428-10468/com.beonews D/JavaScriptCore.Version: 236355.1.0
2019-04-20 18:53:18.974 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: Loaded: libreactnativejni.so
2019-04-20 18:53:18.976 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: About to load: libfb.so
2019-04-20 18:53:18.977 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-main
2019-04-20 18:53:18.978 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-0
2019-04-20 18:53:18.978 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-1
2019-04-20 18:53:18.978 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-2
2019-04-20 18:53:18.980 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-3
2019-04-20 18:53:18.980 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-4
2019-04-20 18:53:18.980 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-5
2019-04-20 18:53:18.980 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-6
2019-04-20 18:53:18.980 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-7
2019-04-20 18:53:18.980 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-8
2019-04-20 18:53:18.981 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-9
2019-04-20 18:53:18.981 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-10
2019-04-20 18:53:18.982 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-11
2019-04-20 18:53:18.982 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so found on /data/app/com.beonews-RuQNHa98khpLrWL4ziWd4A==/lib/x86
2019-04-20 18:53:18.983 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: Not resolving dependencies for libfb.so
2019-04-20 18:53:18.995 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: About to load: libfb.so
2019-04-20 18:53:18.995 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-main
2019-04-20 18:53:18.995 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-0
2019-04-20 18:53:18.996 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-1
2019-04-20 18:53:18.996 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-2
2019-04-20 18:53:18.996 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-3
2019-04-20 18:53:18.996 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-4
2019-04-20 18:53:18.996 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-5
2019-04-20 18:53:18.996 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-6
2019-04-20 18:53:18.997 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-7
2019-04-20 18:53:18.997 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-8
2019-04-20 18:53:18.997 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-9
2019-04-20 18:53:18.997 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-10
2019-04-20 18:53:18.997 10428-10467/com.beonews I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-04-20 18:53:18.997 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-11
2019-04-20 18:53:18.997 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libfb.so found on /data/app/com.beonews-RuQNHa98khpLrWL4ziWd4A==/lib/x86
2019-04-20 18:53:18.997 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: Not resolving dependencies for libfb.so
2019-04-20 18:53:18.998 10428-10468/com.beonews I/com.beonews: Thread[27,tid=10468,Native,Thread*=0xe45ea400,peer=0x12ef2b08,"create_react_context"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/com.beonews-RuQNHa98khpLrWL4ziWd4A==/lib/x86/libfb.so"
2019-04-20 18:53:18.998 10428-10467/com.beonews I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-04-20 18:53:18.998 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: Loaded: libfb.so
2019-04-20 18:53:18.998 10428-10467/com.beonews I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-04-20 18:53:18.998 10428-10467/com.beonews D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2019-04-20 18:53:18.998 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: Loaded: libfb.so
2019-04-20 18:53:18.998 10428-10467/com.beonews W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2019-04-20 18:53:18.998 10428-10467/com.beonews D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2019-04-20 18:53:18.999 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: About to load: libjscexecutor.so
2019-04-20 18:53:18.999 10428-10467/com.beonews D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe2806980: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2019-04-20 18:53:19.000 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-main
2019-04-20 18:53:19.000 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-0
2019-04-20 18:53:19.000 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-1
2019-04-20 18:53:19.000 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-2
2019-04-20 18:53:19.000 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-3
2019-04-20 18:53:19.000 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-4
2019-04-20 18:53:19.001 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-5
2019-04-20 18:53:19.001 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-6
2019-04-20 18:53:19.001 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-7
2019-04-20 18:53:19.001 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-8
2019-04-20 18:53:19.001 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-9
2019-04-20 18:53:19.001 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-10
2019-04-20 18:53:19.001 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so not found on /data/data/com.beonews/lib-11
2019-04-20 18:53:19.001 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: libjscexecutor.so found on /data/app/com.beonews-RuQNHa98khpLrWL4ziWd4A==/lib/x86
2019-04-20 18:53:19.001 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: Not resolving dependencies for libjscexecutor.so
2019-04-20 18:53:19.003 10428-10467/com.beonews D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2806980: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe28037b0)
2019-04-20 18:53:19.005 10428-10468/com.beonews D/SoLoader: Loaded: libjscexecutor.so
2019-04-20 18:53:19.005 10428-10468/com.beonews D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()
2019-04-20 18:53:19.078 10428-10467/com.beonews D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe2806980: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe28037b0)
2019-04-20 18:53:19.118 10428-10468/com.beonews D/ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge.
2019-04-20 18:53:19.122 10428-10468/com.beonews D/ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge
2019-04-20 18:53:19.150 10428-10468/com.beonews D/ReactNative: Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
2019-04-20 18:53:19.150 10428-10468/com.beonews D/ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
2019-04-20 18:53:19.165 10428-10471/com.beonews D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
2019-04-20 18:53:19.166 10428-10471/com.beonews D/ReactNative: CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
2019-04-20 18:53:19.167 10428-10428/com.beonews W/unknown:ReactNative: Packager connection already open, nooping.
2019-04-20 18:53:19.175 10428-10471/com.beonews D/ReactNative: ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
2019-04-20 18:53:19.223 10428-10471/com.beonews W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTGroupViewManager
2019-04-20 18:53:19.226 10428-10471/com.beonews W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTGroupShadowNode
2019-04-20 18:53:19.229 10428-10471/com.beonews W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTShapeViewManager
2019-04-20 18:53:19.230 10428-10471/com.beonews W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTShapeShadowNode
2019-04-20 18:53:19.232 10428-10471/com.beonews W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTTextViewManager
2019-04-20 18:53:19.235 10428-10471/com.beonews W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTTextShadowNode
2019-04-20 18:53:19.237 10428-10471/com.beonews W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.checkbox.ReactCheckBoxManager
2019-04-20 18:53:19.241 10428-10471/com.beonews W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode
2019-04-20 18:53:19.251 10428-10471/com.beonews W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.picker.ReactDialogPickerManager
2019-04-20 18:53:19.254 10428-10471/com.beonews W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager
2019-04-20 18:53:19.256 10428-10471/com.beonews W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.picker.ReactDropdownPickerManager
2019-04-20 18:53:19.264 10428-10471/com.beonews W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollViewManager
2019-04-20 18:53:19.270 10428-10471/com.beonews W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollContainerViewManager
2019-04-20 18:53:19.271 10428-10471/com.beonews W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ReactProgressBarViewManager
2019-04-20 18:53:19.273 10428-10471/com.beonews W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.progressbar.ProgressBarShadowNode
2019-04-20 18:53:19.276 10428-10471/com.beonews W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactScrollViewManager
2019-04-20 18:53:19.289 10428-10471/com.beonews W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager
2019-04-20 18:53:19.295 10428-10471/com.beonews W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager$ReactSliderShadowNode
2019-04-20 18:53:19.296 10428-10471/com.beonews W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager
2019-04-20 18:53:19.299 10428-10471/com.beonews W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager$ReactSwitchShadowccom.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineIm
```

I got tired of this issue since 3 days, tried to update emulator and others

in build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
```

Comment: Need some more information like whether the app installed or not on android pie? Or it crashed after installing on pie. Post the maximum details possible to help you out.

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal the is installed on Android Pie, but it does not load any data it shows only the first window, and it works on the lower versions perfectly.

Comment: post any screenshot?

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal yes https://i.postimg.cc/D0kzg9hd/Screenshot-20190418-164102.jpg

Comment: post it with the question

Comment: The problem is that you are unable to hit the API's using http and android pie makes use of https check out the @mtkopone answer below and follow accordingly your issue will be resolved

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like your app itself is working, but the loading of content is not. 
I'm assuming you are using an HTTP endpoint to load the data?

If so, the difference is that HTTP is not allowed by default in Android Pie.

Either use HTTPS or see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51902630/455187 on how to allow HTTP.