# Http request are still not allowed after enabling it with networkSecurityConfig

Tags: android, http, react-native, android-9.0-pie

I am trying to make a http request to a device which creates its own wifi hotspot and which allows only http requests. With android 8 and lower http request are successful but with android 9 they are failing.
Though with google pixel 2 it seems to be working, which uses android 9.

I have tried to enable android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in AndroidManifest.xml .

I set networkSecurityConfig like suggested in the solution found here [How to allow all Network connection types HTTP and HTTPS in Android (9) Pie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie)

AndroidManifestXml

```
   <application
      android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

network_security_config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found solution. Because the device I was connecting to didn't had internet connection. When I connected manually to device I saw that android 9 showed me popup with following text: wifi has no internet are you sure you want to connect to it.

The solution was to use forceWifi() function, which forces android to use the connection.