# App Showing No Internet Connection in PIE version only

Tags: android, retrofit, android-9.0-pie

My App is working perfectly fine in all android version except Pie version.
In Pie it shows No internet Connection whereas i check it with Wifi and Mobile data..it is no internet problem. This Issue is related to Pie Version.

i Try following solutions:

```
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

But both didnt work.

This is my Login button code, in which it comes in OnFailure

```
private void onLoginUser(String email, String password) {

    Call<LoginModel> call = ApiClient.getClientInstance().getClientService().userlogin(email, password);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginModel>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginModel> call, Response<LoginModel> response) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            LoginModel jsonLoginResult = response.body();

            if (response.code()== 200)  {
                Log.e("Response", response.code() + "");
            }
            if (response.code() == 400 ) {
                Utility.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).showSnackBarLong(response.message(), mLoginActivity);
                return;
            }
            if (response.code() == 404 ) {
                Utility.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).showSnackBarLong(response.message(), mLoginActivity);
                return;
            }
            if (response.code() == 500 ) {
                Utility.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).showSnackBarLong(response.message(), mLoginActivity);
                return;
            }
            if (jsonLoginResult == null ) {
                Utility.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).showSnackBarLong("Data not found", mLoginActivity);
                return;
            }

            if (jsonLoginResult != null && response != null && response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {

                String jError = "" ;
                String jMessage = "" ;
                String jUserStatus = "" ;

                try {
                    jError = String.valueOf(jsonLoginResult.getError());
                    jMessage = String.valueOf(jsonLoginResult.getMessage());
                    jUserStatus = String.valueOf(jsonLoginResult.getStatus());
                }catch (NullPointerException e){
                    Log.d("Result", e+"");
                }

                TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
                String phone_imei= mTelephonyManager.getDeviceId();
                myPreference.saveString(Constants.IMEI_NUMBER , phone_imei);

                if(jUserStatus.equals(0) || jUserStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("0")){
                    myPreference.saveString(Constants.USER_STATUS , "Disapproved");
                }

                if(jUserStatus.equals(1)|| jUserStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
                    myPreference.saveString(Constants.USER_STATUS , "Approved");
                }

                if(jUserStatus.equals(3)|| jUserStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("3")){
                    myPreference.saveString(Constants.USER_STATUS , "Under Process");
                }

                if(jError.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
                    String jUserId = String.valueOf(jsonLoginResult.getId());
                    String jUserApikey = String.valueOf(jsonLoginResult.getApikey());
                    String jUserName = String.valueOf(jsonLoginResult.getName());
                    String jUserEmail = String.valueOf(jsonLoginResult.getEmail().trim());
                    String jUserPhone = String.valueOf(jsonLoginResult.getPhone_no().trim());
                    String jUserRegisterDate = String.valueOf(jsonLoginResult.getCreated_at());
                    String jUserLogin_date = String.valueOf(jsonLoginResult.getLogin_date());
                    String jUserPancardImage = String.valueOf(jsonLoginResult.getPan_card_image());
                    String jUserChequeImage = String.valueOf(jsonLoginResult.getCheque_number_image());
                    String jUserAddressImage = String.valueOf(jsonLoginResult.getAddressProofImage());
                    String jAddress = String.valueOf(jsonLoginResult.getAddress());
                    String jCompanyName = String.valueOf(jsonLoginResult.getCompanyName());
                    String jCountryId = String.valueOf(jsonLoginResult.getCountryId());
                    String jStateId = String.valueOf(jsonLoginResult.getStateId());
                    String jCityId = String.valueOf(jsonLoginResult.getCityId());
                    String jStateName = String.valueOf(jsonLoginResult.getStateName());
                    String jCityName = String.valueOf(jsonLoginResult.getCityName());
                    String jRelationShipManager = String.valueOf(jsonLoginResult.getRelationshipManagerId());



                    Utility.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).showSnackBarLong(jMessage, mLoginActivity);

                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                mUNameLogin.setText("");
                                mPasswordLogin.setText("");
                                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                startActivity(i);
                                LoginActivity.this.finish();

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }, 2000);
                }

                if(jError.equalsIgnoreCase("null")){
                    Utility.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).showSnackBarLong(jMessage, mLoginActivity);
                    return;
                }

                if(jError.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                    popupMessageDialog(jMessage);
                    //return;
                }
            }

            else {
                assert response != null;
                Utility.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).showSnackBarLong(" "+response.message(), mLoginActivity);
                return;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginModel> call, Throwable t) {
            mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (LoginActivity.this != null) {
                Utility.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).showSnackBarLong("No Internet Connection", mLoginActivity);
                return;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: post your code that you are using to check internet connection

Comment: its a long code, i used Retrofit api.

Comment: if it is internet issue, then howz it work in other versions or mobiles

Comment: plz check i post my code

Comment: add the code to your question, not as answer. Also this is not the code I asked for.

Comment: the code i post, in that onFailure method is called everytime ( only in pie )

Comment: Log the `Throwable` that you are getting in `onFailure()` and use Logcat to examine the stack trace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to allow all Network connection types HTTP and HTTPS in Android (9) Pie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie)

Comment: remove this android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow tow thing one remove `networkSecurityConfig` from your application tag and add bellow Code inside of your application tag and try

```
 <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/generalnotitle"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
<uses-library
    android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
    android:required="false" />
```

Comment: Removing networkSecurityConfig and using latest one because tow my friend facing the same issue which resolved by removing networkSecurityConfig and adding uses-library.

Comment: hi guys,  do you have any other solution...or the reason why this is happening

Comment: Hi, I am here trying to find solution for you case.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>

Comment: Right but this is only needed when you want to add some custom configuration.

Comment: Also, can you send me your web URL in the chat box? So I can help you.