# JSONException since Android Api 28 (String result = "")

Tags: android, jsonexception

Upgraded to Android Api 28. Now im getting an curios JSONException. Actually its not clear how I can solve the problem. I know why this is happen, but I don't know how to fix it at this time.

This part should produce the error "String result = "";" and on line 74 on this part "JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);" JSON crashed

GetJsonResults

```
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class GetJsonResults extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    private final static String LOG_TAG = GetJsonResults.class.getSimpleName();

    private static String GET(String url) {
        InputStream inputStream;
        String result = "";
        try {

            // create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // make GET request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url));

            // receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // convert inputstream to string
            if (inputStream != null)
                result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
            else
                result = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        return result;
    }

    private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        String result = "";
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            result += line;

        inputStream.close();
        return result;

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return GET(urls[0]);
    }

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Daten erfolgreich empfangen!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
```

```
2019-07-11 16:59:02.919 10072-10072/com.radio.xxxxxxSRAPPID D/SplashActivity: Get JSON Results
2019-07-11 16:59:04.312 10072-10072/com.radio.xxxxxxSRAPPID D/GetJsonResults: There was an JSONException
2019-07-11 16:59:04.312 10072-10072/com.radio.xxxxxxSRAPPID W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value http of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
2019-07-11 16:59:04.312 10072-10072/com.radio.xxxxxxSRAPPID W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:112)
2019-07-11 16:59:04.312 10072-10072/com.radio.xxxxxxSRAPPID W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:163)
2019-07-11 16:59:04.312 10072-10072/com.radio.xxxxxxSRAPPID W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:176)
2019-07-11 16:59:04.312 10072-10072/com.radio.xxxxxxSRAPPID W/System.err:     at com.radio.xxxxxx.task.GetJsonResults.onPostExecute(GetJsonResults.java:74)
2019-07-11 16:59:04.312 10072-10072/com.radio.xxxxxxSRAPPID W/System.err:     at com.radio.xxxxxx.task.GetJsonResults.onPostExecute(GetJsonResults.java:21)
```

Comment: Post the json string you're trying to parse.

Comment: This seem related to the clear text http. Since Android 9 (API Level 28), Android block http, use https. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted

Comment: Its not the JSON String. When I manually insert the JSON String here "String result = "MYFULLSTRING";" it was working. But then the App only used the parts that I manually entered and not the Dynamically parts that the file normally gets from an url.

Comment: Big thanks @ישו אוהב אותך. android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" was the solution!

Comment: You may also run into this again if you ever hit the condition where you say result = "Did not work!". You should convert that to a json string such as "{error : Did not work!}".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because http calls are disabled by default in API 28, you can use the below work around to enable http calls in API 28,

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, put

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ... >
    <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">




    </application>
</manifest>
```

Create `network_security_config.xml` file in resource directory and paste below source in it,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

**OR** use only `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in app class

This will allow http calls in your app, for more info please check,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51902630/4360419

also documentation here,

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28

Comment: Thanks! I added "android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"" to AndroidManifest.xml under application. This was enough and its working now. Its nothing privacy related, but it seems to be an good idea to switch to https.

Comment: While this is an effective work-around, it is not an ideal solution.  Chrome dropped HTTP support for a reason (it is inherently insecure).  You should really take a look at what part of your system is still relying on the use of HTTP, and see if you can upgrade to HTTPS instead.