# i have created a apk file and i have installed it in 2 devices . But the app is working only in device 1 but no working in device 2

Tags: android, react-native

i have created a apk file and i have installed it in 2 devices
device 1 is having android version of 8
device 2 is having android version of 10

My react native app has a login page and when the device 1 with android version try to login everything is working perfectly fine

when device 2 with version 10 tries to login the api call is not hitting and staying the login page itself

so i tried in my emulator with android version 13 there its working fine

how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: please confirm one thing, that you release apk is working fine on physical devices But api are not working,........In that case follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57289466/react-native-android-app-not-working-in-release)

Comment: Even in the build file i created the apis are not working and when i hit login button nothing happens