# Image loading problem in new devices of android through Picasso lib by image url

Tags: android, picasso

app is running in android older version and image showing perfectly but when its running in newer android version it looks blank in the imageview section.
I have used Picasso.

String image_url = "http://***.com/uploads/user_photo/" + imagelist.get(position).getUser_photo();

```
    Picasso.with(context)
          .load(image_url )
          .into(holder.imgView);
```

Comment: use https see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted

Comment: What is the `old` and `new` android version?

Comment: mean android old version 4.4 (kitkat) and new version 9.0 (Pie) its works fine in kitkat but image is not uploaded in Pie

Comment: I have added 
res/xml/network_security_config.xml and also made domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you mean it doesn't work on Android 9+ but works correctly on Android <= 8.
That's probably the case since the image url you're trying to load uses http. Android 9+ blocks http by default and only accepts https urls.

Check this answer for details on how to enable http on Android 9+ for your application.
[How to allow all Network connection types HTTP and HTTPS in Android (9) Pie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie)

Keep in mind that it's fine when testing but you shouldn't enable http on a production app, they disabled it for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Picasso.get().load("image_url").into(holder.imgView);`

Comment: That means your Picasso library is outdated, updating it could break the project depending on other dependencies

Comment: updated Picasso lib and used Picasso.get().load("image_url").into(holder.imgView);
still same issues

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Picasso.with(context)  // Activity context
       .load("https:URL") // Set URL
       .resize(100,100) // you also Resize the image
       .placeholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.waterMark)) // Default Image
       .error(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.errorImg)) // if errors occurs
       .into(holder.heroesImage); // Your Imageview
```

And Make sure your url is **HTTPS**