# Third party API request failed on production but works on stagging. How to fix this?

Tags: android, api, react-native

I am new to react native. Now I'm debugging some bugs. I debug with android device. There's a feature that called third party API (it using http). One of the param is location (latitude and longitude). It works on my local or stagging. But in production (download my app from Google Play Store) it returns network error, failed to connect. In some phone with works normally. It works on my friend's phone (Android 7, mine is Android 9).

I already tried to disable PlayProtect, download it, then allow location. But it still not working. Then I tried to go to dev setting when debugging, uncheck JS Dev Mode, and check JS Minify, it works! Why? Is there something wrong with code or it's come from API?

Answer (score 3):

It's a duplicate question , but to allow http requests in production , you must add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to your `AndroidManifest.xml` in your project directory.

`

```
<application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
          <uses-library
              android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
              android:required="false" />
     <activity
          android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"/>
</application>
```

`

Please find the link to the answers in a brief format [Add http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie)