# How to get Image through HTTP on Android 9.0 and then crop Image?

Tags: java, android, eclipse-plugin

I used android 7.1.1(API 25) Build-tools before and the version has been upgraded to  8.1.0(API 27) a few days ago...

But now using android 9.0(API 28) and the device is also.

Image Crop function is not working and I can't even load image through HTTP
I need your advice... please help me(;_;)

I'm trying Lib but I don't use `gradle` and I'm using `java 1.6`

```
public void imageForCrop(String imagePath){
   Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(imagePath);
   Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
   intent.setDataAndType(imageUri, "image/*");
   String path = imageUri.getPath();
   path =  path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/"),path.lastIndexOf("."))+"_new.jpg";
   imageUri =Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), path));
   intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
   intent.putExtra("scale", true);
   intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
   callerObject.startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_FOR_CROP);
}
```

Comment: you need to only use `HTTPS`. otherwise, detour.

Comment: `com.android.camera.action.CROP` is not mandatory to be present on the device. You should not expect it to work. What exactly is a problem with `to HTTP Image`?

Comment: Vladyslav Matviienko
load from HTTP Image

Comment: ok, that is what you want, but **what is the problem**?

Comment: showing graybackground, exclamation mark

Comment: ok, I Want get image from HTTP and then Crop this image.

Comment: `showing graybackground` where? After you do what? Which code you execute?

Comment: I think `intent.setDataAndType(imageUri, "image/*");`  this code `imageUri` is can not setData

Comment: I'm using webview, So get image url in html and then call `imageForCrop` function, give url to `imagePath`. So I Can see some white border Crop Frame But I can't see the Image

Comment: you likely will have to download it manually from URL before cropping

Comment: Okay~ I will try your recommend Thanks `Vladyslav Matviienko` I'm leave work~^ enjoy Friday Night! really really thank you so much bro!

Comment: FYI: You need to use `@VladyslavMatviienko` to mention me in your comment, otherwise I won't get notification

Answer (score 0):

Maybe HTTP request don't enable in Android 8 & 9.

The easy way to implement this is to use this attribute to your AndroidManifest.xml where you allow all http for all requests:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: I found a good answer for HTTP request in Android 8, 9. **Try** [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie)

Comment: I'm tried 'network_security_config.xml' and Download image but it's not working T_T