# Why does Android 10 HTTPUrlConnection fail? Worked fine on 9

Tags: android, exception, httpurlconnection

With this code

```
  URL url = new URL(data.replaceAll(" ", "%20"));
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(12000);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(12000);
        int xy = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
```

I'm getting this exception:

```
data = "http://myrpd.us/api/staff1?lang=eng"
urlConnection = {HttpURLConnectionImpl@11410}    "com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl:http://myrpd.us/api/staff1?lang=eng"
e = {UnknownHostException@11411} "java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "myrpd.us": No address associated with hostname"
```

The URL works fine on  9 and in a browser.
I've read all the privacy information that's new with 10.  I have this in the manifest:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error may also occur when there is no Internet connection

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host
```

Can you check the Internet connection on your Android 10 device?

Comment: This problem is occuring on the emulator/simulator, and my Mac clearly has internet connection.

Comment: I have tried your code to be sure. It was worked on my emulator(Nexus 5X API 29 Android 10). Finally, make sure that the emulator's Wi-Fi or mobile data is turned on. That's what I think of.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  I've never before seen an emulator start without wifi automatically running through Android Studio.  I thought the problem was somehow related to 10's Privacy features.  Thank you serkancay.