# Http failure response for (My adress url api ): 0 Unknown Error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I created an apiRest Full with node that works well in my project ionic, I access very well the browser and even some less android phone version 9 but higher than 9, I have the error :

> "Http failure response for (api address): 0 Unknown Error "

Can some give me some solution track?
Thank you for your answers
ionic 5.2

Comment: Just make sure you have `https` support.Because in higher version of andriod it requires secure connection.

Comment: check this. It may heps you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie

Comment: Thank you for your proposals after a search momonent, I finally find a solution
It was necessary to modify the file:
'network_security_config.xml' that was in the directory
resources / android / xml

change localhost with with the server ip

Thank you

Comment: So the above ref URL helped you? Because in that URL, Developer had also changed `network` file.

Comment: Yes it guided me to the right problem solving

thank you very much

Comment: Okay so I'm adding this same in answer. So it may helps others too. :)

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure you have https support. Because in a higher version of Andriod it requires a secure connection.

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie) it may help you. :)