# Axios requests is not working in React-native released apk in android latest api level pie?

Tags: android, xmlhttprequest, react-native, redux-thunk, android-9.0-pie

I am unable to send an API request with any library like Axios fetch to a server with released APK 
in react-native in android pie 
In debug APK everything is working fine but in released APK not working

I have deployed my server on digital ocean with https protocol and the server is written in flask

my react-native version is 0.59.1
react 16..8.3

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in AndroidManifest.xml  is also not working

I really need an expert opinion and suggestion that what should I do now 
it's been one month that I am unable to resolve this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie

Comment: android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" did'nt work for me

Comment: Did you debug your app to check the error?

Comment: did you find the solution? I am having the same issue!

Answer (score 3):

Just change HTTP to HTTPS, Will solve the problem.

Comment: where should I apply this change? I use an HTTPS source

Answer (score 0):

pass this android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in application tag in AndroidManifest.xml file it work

Answer (score -2):

/// add this line to android manifest to use http when releasing apk in react native

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).