# Android Studio warning " Setting <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"/> is not recommended."

Tags: android, payumoney, android-network-security-config

I'm integrating PayUMoney with my app. For Android versions above 9 `cleartextTrafficPermitted="false"` by default. So I get the following error:

> The webpage at http://180.179.174.15:3000/pgSimulator/axis/redirect
> could not be loaded because: net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED

So in `network_security_config.xml`, I changed it to `true` as below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"/>
</network-security-config>
```

And now Android Studio shows:

> Setting   is not
> recommended.

Now is it safe to set it to false? If I don't set it to false. PayUMoney does not work. So what to do now?

Comment: You have to add your domain, Check my answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to allow all Network connection types HTTP and HTTPS in Android (9) Pie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie)

Comment: Just register a host-name & install an SSL certificate, in order to fix this properly... else you are running a payment gateway with plain-text traffic, which is extremely stupid (unless this is only for testing purposes).

Answer (score 1):

Either use

```
<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    ....
</application>
```

Or set config like below with domain:

```
<network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">Your_domain</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: What is "Your_domain" here? I am using Firebase realtime database for my android app. I don't have any domain.

Comment: Then just use `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`. No need about config

Comment: And from your log, probably this is your domain. `http://180.179.174.15:3000`

Comment: I am sorry to say that putting android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"> in Manifest does not work. It gives me this error- Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@usesCleartextTraffic value=(true) from AndroidManifest.xml:20:9-44
 is also present at [com.payu.custombrowser:payu-custom-browser:7.5.1] AndroidManifest.xml:17:18-54 value=(false).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:usesCleartextTraffic"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:11:5-38:19 to override.

Comment: Also <network-security-config>
  <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">Your_domain</domain>
  </domain-config>
</network-security-config> does not work

Comment: For the first problem use `tools:replace="android:usesCleartextTraffic"` in your application tag with `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

Comment: I am sorry to say again that it is not working. I am so thankful for what you did.