# CLEARTEXT communication to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is not permitted by network security policy

Tags: java, android

This is the Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:name=".Dao.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".FoundActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".LPcapActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".RentActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MPxtActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".LPanActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".LDtileActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".TabActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:noHistory="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.stk.android.compapp.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

I have created XML file(network_security_config.xml) under XML folder

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">http://121.345.678.90:7744/KBB/Kbblist</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true"> http://111.234.177.123:1100</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

I tried with options available in this link also 
[android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted) 
Still, I will get this error which is saying **CLEARTEXT communication is not permitted by the network security policy**

Comment: If you change `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in network_secrity_config.xml, Android Studio complans like `Setting  <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"/> is not recommended.` Recommended way to add this permission with related Domain. Check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58898167/1744705)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just add this in application tag in your manifest-:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Here

```
<application
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:name=".Dao.MyApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

I hope it helps!!

Comment: why this line android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" along dosent work

Comment: @isuru I had the same problem. inside the network_security_config file get rid of the http:// part in the domain AND it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Try with below security config code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: Still, I'm getting that Exception

Comment: try removing the clearTextTraffic attribute from your application tag in manifest

Comment: no bro is their way to find out network-security-config is pointed?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: no, Still got that Exception

Comment: <application
    android:name="....."
    android:icon="@mipmap/..."
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:resizeableActivity="false"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    tools:replace="icon">