# can't send http request on android release apk (built in react-native)

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I am sending an HTTP request with dummy username and password to test the my App.

On working with non-release variants i.e `react-native run-android`, I am capable of sending http requests to the server and receive a token, thus, logging in. However, this is not true when I try it on the release version of the apk `react-native run-android --variant=release`

Note: It allow works on ios after making

```
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You must add the following code to `AndroidManifest.xml` file to allow http requests.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

For more information look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie)