# React-native android does not build when i add networkSecurityConfig tag

Tags: android, react-native

As I found in this [article](https://www.nccgroup.trust/uk/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blogs/2017/november/bypassing-androids-network-security-configuration/).
I want to update my network security config to allow root certificates from the personal store of my android emulator.
but when I do this, I cant build my app anymore. The error message:

> Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running a metro server
>   (run 'react-native-start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle'
>   is packaged correctly for release.

when i remove `android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` its all running fine again..

Does anyone know what to do? or has an other way of making changes to the security config?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, finally found it ! :)

React-Native needs *clear text traffic* for the build. The network security config file should contain this:

```xml
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
```

I have a tag in `src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<application tools:targetApi="28" tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning" 
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/react_native_config" />
```

and created a file `src/debug/res/xml/react_native_config.xml` with:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user"/>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: Could you share where did you found that information, please?

Comment: add the tag:
    <application 
        tools:targetApi="28" tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/react_native_config" />

to src/debug/androidManifext.xml

and create a file:
src/debug/res/xml/react_native_config.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user"/>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51902629/7178860 more details

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem while adding the IP (subdomain)

I did this

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="user"/>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>

    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain>your-ip-address-1</domain>
        <domain>your-ip-address-2</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```