# I converted my website to app it works normal in AVD but it dose not work in my phone

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I converted my website into an app, it works properly in AVD but it does not work on my phone. I'm getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXkDF.jpg) error.

Comment: The error is `err_cleartext_not_permitted`. You need to use HTTPS.

Comment: Please post text, not links to images of text.

Answer (score 0):

From Android 9 all requests through http protocol will be blocked by default. You can add networkSecurityConfig to your Manifest file. But I recommend use only https.  Please refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51902630/12967117 for more explanations how to allow using http.