# How to perform a simple HTTP request in Kotlin/Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask, kotlin-coroutines

I am quite new to Android app development and would like to perform a simple API request via HTTP to a web server. `URL("http://www.myapi.com").readText()` seems to be a good way to start with, but this leads to a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. So it must run asynchronously or in a coroutine. However, I'm not familiar enough with this and other examples I have found so far don't work for me.

Thanks a lot already for your help!

Comment: [retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/). don't really have to say much more :)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mvvm pattern you can do the following in your ViewModel class

```
viewModelScope.launch {val response = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { your request }}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP requests are no longer allowed by default on Android 9 and above.
Consider using HTTPS, or modify the `AndroidManifest.xml`, see [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51902630/14350146).