# How to make a http request for a native fyne app on android

Tags: android, go, gomobile, fyne

I am unable to make a http request from a Go fyne application running on android, below is a simple example to show the issue

```
package main

import (

     "io/ioutil"
     "net/http"
     "log"
 
    "fyne.io/fyne"
    "fyne.io/fyne/app"
    "fyne.io/fyne/widget"
 
)


func main() {

    app := app.New()
    w := app.NewWindow("Android http issue")
    w.SetContent(widget.NewVBox(
        widget.NewLabel("Run test"),
        widget.NewButton("Connect", func() {
             go func() {
                HttpGetData(w)
             }()
        
        }),
    ))
    w.ShowAndRun()
} 
 

func HttpGetData( win fyne.Window) {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://date.jsontest.com/" )
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("%v", err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    bodyBytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    StartScreen(win,  string(bodyBytes))

}

func StartScreen(win fyne.Window, data string) {
    l := widget.NewLabel("data" +data)
    win.SetContent(l)

}
```

I can run the code on linux with `go run -tags mobile . -t`
first screen
[image: entry screen running on linux]

then I can fire the event to make a http get request to the remote server and see the http  response in the gui
[image]

as we can see everything works via `go run -tags mobile . -t`  on linux

now I package as an apk using fyne
`fyne package -os android -appID basic.client -icon ico.png` 
install with adb `adb install  <path to apk>/basicExample.apk`

When I run the app in android I get to the first screen, then fire the event as before.
The http request is never fired, I only get a crytpic error in logcat

`F/libc    ( 4711): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 4739 (basic.client)`
`E/InputDispatcher(  535): channel '344d7ddf basic.client/org.golang.app.GoNativeActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!`

any help would be greatly appreciated

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="basic.client"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0">

        <application android:label="Client" android:debuggable="true">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

        <activity android:name="org.golang.app.GoNativeActivity"
                android:label="Client"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
                <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="client" />
                <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        </application>
</manifest>
```

UPDATE from comment
android version 28
golang version go1.14.4 linux/amd64
fyne version fyne.io/fyne v1.3.0

Update 2
Added following attributes to the application tag in the manifest
`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28"`

Results in following error for the `fyne package` command
`failed to find table ref by "attr/usesCleartextTraffic"`

I added a print statement to the `fyne package` command to log the build environment variables, this is what they look like

```
GOOS=android   
GOARCH=arm   
CC={path to}/ndk/21.2.6472646/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi16-clang   
CXX={path to}/ndk/21.2.6472646/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/armv7a-linux-androideabi16-clang++   
CGO_ENABLED=1   
GOARM=7
```

Comment: maybe you should include your various go, fyne, android versions.

Comment: thanks mh-cbon good point updated question

Comment: It *might* be related that [Android blocks HTTP traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45940861) (or [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51902629)), but the error message is quite cryptic.

Comment: thanks xarantolus for the link will try the clear-text workarounds and update with the result

Comment: You are continuing on error as well, so it could be that the crash is after the call perhaps? Is the server getting the request?

Comment: From the server logs the request is never made, I have tried various permutations but always the code fails on resp, err := http.Get("http://date.jsontest.com/" ) and the only logcat error as posted, err I believe is nil

Comment: Can you try printing the value of the err and body to verify that one of them is not ni?

Comment: It looks like the usesCleartextTraffic tag is not supported by fyne package at this time, should have been addressed in 1.3.0 but will get added now you point it out

Comment: @andy.xyz definitely will try both as u suggest

Answer (score 1):

With the latest version of Fyne we have fixed some issues with the packager and Android manifest. Internet permission is not enabled by default, but if you add it under the storage permission definitions it should now work.

We are working on better permission request code that will work cross platform, should be published later this year.