# How to add the URL in <domain> dynamically in network-security-config.xml file Android

Tags: android, android-xml, android-network-security-config

For some reason, I need to let user input the url in runtime and let it be the whitelist url, therefore need to write it into the `<domain>` of network-security-config.xml. Have found similar questions, but not answers.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56235810/9346054

Comment: Hi, for some reasons, I need to use network_security_config.xml or other methods to configure the whitelist url each time, and I can't allow connections to just any url, which is the suggestion in your link. Thx.