# i converted website into app using webview. but website background is not appearing in my app

Tags: android

```xml
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mywebview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wordpress);
        mywebview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebview.loadUrl("https://www.indianfests.com/");
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mywebview.canGoBack()) {
            mywebview.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing these lines `mywebview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wordpress); mywebview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

Answer (score 0):

Remove following...

```
mywebview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wordpress);
mywebview.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

from XMl:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the background image with the elephant statue that we see on https://www.indianfests.com/ is not loading: this is probably because [Android requires all requests to use HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie) by default from target API level 28 onwards.

The background image, however, is specified as plain HTTP: `http://www.indianfests.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/wordpress.jpg`. The server immediately redirects it to HTTPS, but because the HTTP request is blocked, the WebView cannot know that (and even if it did, it would be insecure to use it anyway). You can also see this in a regular web browser, which should show some kind of warning text or icon in the address bar.

**So the best way to fix this is to simply change the website to use HTTPS throughout.**

If you absolutely, positively cannot do that, you can use `<application android:usesClearTextTraffic="true">` in your manifest ([documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic)). But for the security of your users, please consider this a last resort.