# Flutter error: Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform

Tags: flutter, dart

When I run my Flutter app that makes a network connection to an HTTP URL, I get an error:
**Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform**

I get an exception like this every time I make a network request using Dio.

```
DioError [DioErrorType.DEFAULT]: Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform: <my_private_api_url>
```

Comment: you might need to give us more context here. What exact command are you running? what version of flutter are you on, etc...

Comment: You can use [edit] link below your post to edit your question instead of posting information as an answer

Comment: Please have a look [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/network-policy-ios-android#migration-guide). Under the Migration section, you can find instructions for iOS and Android.

Comment: read this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie.  I have solved this problem.@Ahmad Mohy

Comment: @Ahmad how did you solve this problem ?

Comment: For iOS
Add this line in Xcode project info.plist

`<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
<key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
<true/>
</dict>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64197752/1318946

Comment: this showing because of not using API using HTTP and flutter the latest version of the android version not allow HTTP  user HTTPS.