# Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform:

Tags: node.js, flutter, http, mobile, connection

I'm having the following problem:
E/flutter ( 7144): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform: http://myIPv4:PORT/PATH.

[image: This is my flutter code to requisition]

And this is the backend that I can access:
[image: My backend code]

I already allowing the access by cors, but not even this help me.
I already tried to use the http://localhost:port/path and http://myIP:port/path but doesn't worked!

But if I try access directly by browser so work.

[image: Browser Print]

Comment: `var response = await http.get(http://IPV4:port/);` try like this

Answer (score 132):

### For Android:

This behavior may be omitted following migration guide: https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/network-policy-ios-android.

or... Just add in **`android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:`**

`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` to `<application />` also dont forget to take **INTERNET** PERMISSION:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <!-- This Line -->

<application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="receipt"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" <!-- This Line -->
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
```

### For iOS:

Allow insecure/HTTP requests globally across your application on iOS, you can add this to your **ios/Runner/info.plist** under the main dictionary definition:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
</dict>
```

Be warned that you will need to have an explanation for Apple's review team when enabling this, otherwise your app will get rejected on submission.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm getting error while adding the code for iOS. Could you please elaborate more on how to add that in info.plist @Pratik Butani

Comment: You can check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31216758/how-can-i-add-nsapptransportsecurity-to-my-info-plist-file

Comment: If also it is not working so please update the Flutter and android studio.

Comment: If it is not working at some point, close the app and rebuild again.

Comment: Don't forget to restart the Emulator after editing AndroidManifest.xml (under both debug and main directory). It's not incorporated in the Flutter Hot Reload ;)

Answer (score 54):

1. Navigate to your project.
2. Go to yourapp\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml.
3. Add this line.

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
</application>
```

For further details, follow [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/solving-the-new-https-requirements-in-flutter-7abe240fbf23) link.

Comment: It worked for android only. What's the solution for ios?

Comment: Given solution in my answer. please check @DhirajBaruah

Comment: This works if you are using local servers. Thankyou

Answer (score 15):

This problem is solved here.

https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/network-policy-ios-android

You just need to change the HTTP to HTTPS.
Like this

Response response = await get('https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Africa/Nairobi');

Answer (score 6):

I solved it by following this step:

1. android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
   then write

   ```
   <application
   android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
   android:label="laundry"
   android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
   <uses-library
    android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
    android:required="false" />  </application>
   ```