# Flutter internet conneciton not working real device

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-android

Hello I have App in Play Store. I updated the app and flutter 2.0 but when ı download the app in playstore internet connection not working. I builded release mode and send the normal phone internet connection working but if someone want the download the app in playstore connection is not working ı don't understand where is the problem.

This is my main Androidmanifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.agronet_seracilik">
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />   
         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />  
    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="Agronet Seracılık A.Ş"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">``
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    
</manifest>
```

Comment: Have you tried : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65578828/1318946

Comment: Now it's working thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give permission to application in manifest

```
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="Agronet Seracılık A.Ş"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"> --> Add this line to send http request after flutter 2.0
```

Comment: I tried that one but didn't worked. I think is problem different