# Change in android manifest missing when I run the project

Tags: android, flutter, android-manifest

So I've just upgraded my Flutter to Flutter 2, while facing incompatibilities here and there I found an error regarding connection due to the platform that I'm using is not secure yet. So I followed the solution provided from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64197752/bad-state-insecure-http-is-not-allowed-by-platform/65578828#65578828). But whenever I put a new line, save it, and run the project the lines keep missing.

Here's the snippet of my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mr.flutter.plugin.filepicker" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent>
    </queries>

</manifest>
```

Comment: After modifying the Manifest, did you try to run gradle ?

Comment: @BabC yes, Flutter would automatically run gradle when a project is initiated to run

Comment: Your project can contain several manifests, make sure, that you editing the right file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess here is that you're editing the wrong AndroidManifest.xml.

The AndroidManifest.xml you have to edit is located in `android/app/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

The snippet you provided looks like the AndroidManifest of the debug folder which is re-created every build (which explains why your modifications are erased)