# Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform - usesClearTextTraffic not worked

Tags: android, flutter

I'm trying to run a basic API call in Flutter using PHP and a MySQL database, but I'm receiving an error which reads:

`E/flutter ( 7461): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform`

**What I've Tried**

I have tried the solution proposed here: [Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64197752/bad-state-insecure-http-is-not-allowed-by-platform)

and here: https://www.programmersought.com/article/49295775092/

**Sample Code**

home.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_crud/env.sample.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  void getData() async{
    Response response = await get(Uri.parse("${Env.URL_PREFIX}/list"));
    Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(data);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter CRUD API'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body:Center(
          child: Text('Hello'),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

The URI prefix comes from env.sample.dart:

```
class Env{
  static String URL_PREFIX = "http://[my.IP.address.here]/flutter_crud";
}
```

In the debug/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="jacobcollinsdev.flutter_crud">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"/>
</manifest>
```

In the main/AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="jacobcollinsdev.flutter_crud">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <------- I added this line
    <application
        android:label="flutter_crud"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"> <------ I added this line
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
        <uses-library 
            android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
            android:required="false" /> <-------I added this code block
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Finally, I have also created this file in android/app/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config clearTextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

So far nothing has resolved the error and I'm all out of ideas. Any feedback would be grand!

Comment: Update: I have also tried running `flutter clean`, with no success.

Comment: did u solve it ?

Comment: @abed nope, unforuntately not!

Answer (score 2):

simply these lines in
**`android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`**

> 1). Add **`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`**
> before **`application`** tag

> 2). Add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` inside **`application`** tag

Answer (score 0):

You should try loading your images from a SSL certificate domain. That is using `HTTPS` rather than `HTTP`.

So for your case, replace `"http://[my.IP.address.here]/flutter_crud"` to use `https://`.