# I have been facing this insecure http error while i try to login into my application

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

This is what I get when I try to login to my application using an api.
Please check the screenshot of my error.

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform:(url of the api)
```

Comment: Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64197752/bad-state-insecure-http-is-not-allowed-by-platform), maybe a duplicate one.

Answer (score 0):

Add this Into Your Manifest:

```
  android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Example:

```
<application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</application>
```