# API Returning null on the Screen in Flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I have used [Numbers Api](http://numbersapi.com/random/trivia) for my application, but when pressed a button it show null on the screen. Also my API contains only String.

Here is my code for API:

```
String fact;
  Future fetchData() async {
    Response response;
    response = await get(Uri.https('numbersapi.com', 'random/trivia'));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print(response.statusCode);
      setState(() {
        fact = response.body;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
   .....
```

Since Text widget not accept null values, I converted it to `toString()` -

```
              fact.toString(),
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
```

But when `fetchData()` is passed in onPressed Property of the Elevated Button, it shows null on the screen.

How do I display a fact on screen instead of null?

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: can you put the button code also?

Comment: @Pushpendra Yeah its just - ```child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      fetchData();
                    },```

Comment: Also when I `print(fetchData());` it gives -`Instance of 'Future<dynamic>'`

Comment: You need to `await`

Comment: @Pushpendra I already did that....

Answer (score 0):

Initially, the fact will be *null* until data is fetched. So either you can show some indicator that data is being fetched as following

```
fact == null ? Show Loading Message : Text(fact);
```

OR show an empty string like the following.

```
Text(fact ?? "")
```

For button

```
FlatButton(child: Text("Load"), onPressed: () async => await fetchData())
```

Edit:

Got the exact problem. The URL that you are trying to get the data from is not a secure URL. It is `http` not `https`

Hence try following while fetching data.

```
await get(Uri.http('numbersapi.com', 'random/trivia'))
```

[Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64197752/bad-state-insecure-http-is-not-allowed-by-platform/65578828) Check this for Insecure HTTP Connection.

Comment: if fact is null, that means the API is not working fine..

Comment: @NightyKnight I have updated the comment. Check now it should work fine.

Comment: Its giving error - `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform: http://numbersapi.com/random/trivia
`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64197752/bad-state-insecure-http-is-not-allowed-by-platform/65578828

Comment: Cool. Please update whatever comment/answer was helpful.