# Local Connection with WiFi to a device and Post Data from android

Tags: android, https, retrofit2, local

I have a Device with 192.168.4.1 ip address and want post data from android to it. what is the best way to do that? for more information the big problem is Https security protected from android 9 and upper. I want make it with Retrofit2.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/51902630/6094503 for http problem

Comment: @navid My host is an ip address and i try this solution but i cant connect yet. Can you more explain about it.

Comment: First try sending a request from your phone's browser. If it works check out the problem with your app. See if you get any relevant logs after sending the request.

Comment: @navid Dear Navid My problem is fake SSL in my device and my phone (Android 10) can't accept it. How can i disable Android 10 SSL verify in android studio?

Comment: Could you share some logs or screen shots of the problem?