# Http failure response for xxx 0 Unknown Error

Tags: android, postgraphile

PostGraphile v4.9.2 server listening on port 5001

‣ GraphQL API:         http://0.0.0.0:5001/graphql

how can i change http to https. i mean, i want **https**://0.0.0.0:5001/graphql

because, i am getting error while debugging my ionic capacitor app for android

E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/vendor-es2018.js - Line 41539 -
Msg: ERROR Error: Http failure response for http:// mydomain .com:5001/graphql: 0 Unknown Error

i think it is about http problem but as you see it is unknown error. Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure that causes the unknown error: you can not use IP V4 address 0.0.0.0. That's a special adress. If you listen on a socket for 0.0.0.0, that means: Listen to all ip addresses (interfaces) the operating system is aware of.According to the error message the system translates 0.0.0.0 to `http:// mydomain .com:5001/graphql`. There is an space character where it should not be. Look for a specific address of your computer, or use localhost. ` http://localhost:5001/graphql` or (just an example) `http://192.168.0.100:5001/`. Localhost only works if server and client are on the same machine.

Comment: PostGraphile v4.10.0 server listening on port 5001 

  ‣ GraphQL API:         http://192.168.38.4:5001/graphql (database is in the same ip)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you try to tell us with the last comment. Why is the database ip relevant? And, I had not read the question carefully. You wrote about an Android app. Connecting from a phone or tablet to a PC only works if you configure the App with the right IP address of the server: Let's say `http://192.168.38.4:5001/graphql`. That only works if the phone/tablet uses the same IP subnet. I guess `192.168.38.0/24` in your case: i.e. the IP address of the mobile is `192.168.38.xxx` with xxx is something between 1 and 254 including 1 and 254.

Comment: If you use a simulator on the same PC (Debug??) you should be sure the simulator is configured with an IP address in the same subnet.

Answer (score -1):

i found the solution here: [How to allow all Network connection types HTTP and HTTPS in Android (9) Pie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie)
i allowed http requests in manifest.xml and i added networkSecurityConfig.xml
Thank you all