# Xamarin Webview "Webpage Not Available"

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webview

So, I am new on xamarin mobile form development and created a blank form included this webview code but I am getting this error. I can view the website using the android emulator browser and my PC browser.

Not really sure how to solve this. Tried editing the properties>android manifest> checking internet but still not working.

Help? :3

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie

Comment: thanks bro! this solves my problem