# Unable to fetch data using http.get flutter with a working api

Tags: api, flutter, http, get, uri

**Context**

I have an API (http) that i can access with the GET method via Postman without any issue.
I wanted to fetch data from this API for my flutter app using the http package.

**Issue**

While making the network request, with http.get() method of the http package, like below, I couldn't fetch data from the API.

```
Future<Product> fetchProducts(String barcodeId) async {
var vPath = '/products/' + barcodeId;
var vUri = new Uri(
  scheme: 'http',
  host: 'product.acirfa.tech',
  port: 3000,
  path: vPath,
);
// /products/224213463241
print(vPath);
// http://product.acirfa.tech:3000/products/224213463241
print(vUri);
var response = await http.get(vUri);
print(response);
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print('OK');
} else {
  print('KO');
}}
```

I have printed out the URI (vUri) that I passed as argument to the http.get() method and by clicking on it, I get the data via browser. The print out of the variable "response" is not executed, which makes me think the issue comes from vUri. Although, I have tried to create the  URI with the URI Http constructor[Uri.http()], I saw the same behaviour.

**Expected Result**

I expected to see the print out OK

Any thoughts on where i am going wrong ? Thanks :)

Comment: use: `Uri.parse('http://product.acirfa.tech:3000/products/224213463241')`

Comment: I have already tried to put it directly in the http.get() but didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion !

Comment: Might be it is because of Android 9 or upper version you should try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie

Answer (score 0):

```
final _uri = Uri.http('www.domainName.com', 'furtherLink/page.php', {'key': '$value'});

final response = await http.get(
        _uri, 
        headers: {'authorization':'$_auth'}
).catchError((error) {
  throw error;
});

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print('OK');
} else {
  print('KO');
}}
```

Since you are using http & not https, it is considered unsecured. Make sure to pass the permission.

NOTE: in case of using unsecured network, it will be difficult to publish your app on Android & IOS.