# Images with URI sources does not display after creating release bundle

Tags: android, react-native, android-bundle

I've always created my release bundles by running the command `./gradlew bundleRelease`, however, I recently discovered that images with sources from the backend doesn't get to display, while static ones do.

Earlier, I misunderstood the problem to be that static images weren't displaying at all. Then I got suggestions to run
`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/`, this however created duplicate resources which I had to delete. This turned out not to be the problem since static images were correctly getting render. I haven't found any related solution yet, but would be glad to hear suggestions. Below is what a fraction of my `app/build.gradle` looks like:

```
project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
    bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
    bundleInRelease: true,
    bundleInDebug: true
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
               :
               :
               :
apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
```

P.S: Creating apk builds with `./gradlew assembleDebug` works perfectly.

Comment: What version of react native are you using?

Comment: I'm using 0.63.3

Comment: Could your release environment be connecting to a different backend API route?

Comment: A doubt that is possible. How possible could that be?

Comment: Doesn't seem like that's the issue in your case. Was asking as I have a separate backend for production and sometimes this happens. Maybe you can try using a random img url from the internet and see if it's something wrong with the component itself.

Comment: Okay. But I'm reluctant about the approach because it works perfectly on apk builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of fruitless debugging, I got to discover the error wasn't from my code.

Cloudinary, which was serving images from the backend, was returning my images as http instead of https images. And android  versions 9 and above wouldn't render http images on release except I ask it to in my AndroidManifest.xml. So, I solved it by doing that. You can reference this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie) on how to do that.