# Problem cordova project Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'XXXX

Tags: javascript, android, json, cordova

Hello i have this error on my cordova project multiple website say i a problem of android do you have solution for that

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(33)] "Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'XXXXX'.
    at BaseDeDonneesDAO.obtenirListeSentiers (file:///android_asset/www/donnees/BaseDeDonneesDAO.js:29:19)
    at VueTableauBord.afficher (file:///android_asset/www/vues/VueTableauBord.js:8:49)
    at App.naviguer (file:///android_asset/www/App.js:25:33)
    at file:///android_asset/www/App.js:7:63", source: file:///android_asset/www/donnees/BaseDeDonneesDAO.js (33)
[INFO:CONSOLE(8)] "undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/vues/VueTableauBord.js (8)
```

Code:

```
obtenirListeSentiers(){
    try{
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("GET", "XXXX", false);
        // xhttp.setRequestHeader("id", idSentier);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("requete", "obtenirListeSentiers");
        xhttp.send();
        this.listeSentiers = xhttp.responseText;
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err.stack)
    }
    return this.listeSentiers;
}
```

Comment: What is XXXX ??

Comment: is the ip address of my serveur

Comment: Hello after 3 days to search i resolve the problem. Is from android. watch this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie