# Http Request work on Android Emulator but not in Android device - Xamarin cross-platform

Tags: c#, android, http, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have created an API and an application with Xamarin (cross-platform, for Android and iOS both). The first screen is a login page that perform an HTTP request to API. It works fine on Android Emulator, but not in Android device that I have connected with debug mode.
I have already add the string '' in applicationhost.config and my operation are all async operation.
Can i solve it?

Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: Is your API hosted on an IIS server? or you are just in debug mode?

Comment: My API is on IIS server of my localhost. Http request is on 10.0.0.2:44337/urlapi

Comment: Is it hosted or running in the debug mode ? Can you make a call to your API using `http://127.0.0.1:44337/urlapi`?

Comment: Is running in debug mode, from Visual Studio. If I call 127.0.0.1/urlapi with Android device I have a "Connection denied". If I call 10.0.0.2/urlapi it never return.

Comment: Better to host your API to IIS server and try. `Localhost` is not accessible from out of the computer env. To access it on local network, host the api to your `IIS` server instead of inbuilt `IIS Express` of visual studio.

Comment: How can I host my API on IIS server? Thansk a lot

Comment: Ok, I try. Thank you very much. I hope to solve it!

Comment: the dev IIS server in VS cannot handle remote requests by default,  You need to enable remote requests in the config.  This is exhaustively documented

Comment: Ok, I tried to host my API to IIS, byt unsuccessfull.

Comment: Now, I've tried with iisexpress-proxy package from npm and it work. But now in android device I have the following message, "The ssl connection could not be established see inner exception". I have already set the HttpClientHandler.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you may be using HTTP instead of HTTPS. Newer versions of Android require you to take special steps to allow "insecure" HTTP only calls. See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element#usesCleartextTraffic).

You definitely should use HTTPS in your final product in which case this wouldn't be necessary. In the meantime, you may be using a self-signed SSL certificate, add the `android:usesCleartextTraffic` XML attribute to your  XML tag in the manifest:

```xml
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" ... >
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51902630) goes into more detail as well.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to bypass the certificate using below code.

```
 HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
 clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; };   

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler)
```

Comment: Yes, I've already tried this. With this I bypass the certificates in Android Emulator, but not in Android phisically device.

Comment: @MarcoSpallone This code will essentially disable SSL certificate checks. You don't want to leave this code in your released app.