# .NET Maui: How to show an external image in webview

Tags: .net, webview, maui

How can I achieve that eg. the following HTML code displays an image in a Maui webview in the Android emulation?

```
<!DOCTYPE html><HTML>
<BODY>
<H1>.NET MAUI</H1>
<P>Welcome to Yahoo.</P>
<img src="https://s.yimg.com/rz/p/yahoo_homepage_en-US_s_f_p_bestfit_homepage.png" alt="Yahoo Image">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Are there any settings to be made to the webview?

Comment: Have you tried this?  Are you having a problem?

Comment: The image is not displayed.

Comment: Sorry for my posting. The problem in my specific case was using "http". I should have used "https". That's why the Yahoo example works.

Comment: there are numerous existing questions that discuss Android restrictions on non-https requests

Comment: I tested the code you provided, and it works well. You said that your specific case was using "http". Could you provide the link using "http"? Have you tried to open that link in your browser to see if it works?

Comment: In the browser "http" works. In webview only "https".

Comment: You can refer to this link about [How to allow all Network connection types HTTP and HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie). It could be helpful to you.