# iOS or Android Simulator not able to connect to firebase emulator functions

Tags: xcode, firebase, android-emulator, firebase-tools

I am developing a Progressive Web App using Firebase Hosting, Authentication and Functions. For local testing i use the Firebase emulators and iOS / Android Simulators.

The app is hosted using Webpack devServer over SSL. To be able to use SSL locally a RootCA, private and public keys are created and configured in de Webpack devServer configuration.

```
    devServer: {
      watchFiles: ['src/**/*.tsx', 'src/**/*.scss'],
      historyApiFallback: true,
      host: '0.0.0.0',
      allowedHosts: [
        'localhost',
        'theme.myapp.nl',
        'theme-a.myapp.nl',
        'theme-b.myapp.nl'
      ],
      hot: false,
      liveReload: false,
      port: 8800,
      server: {
        type: 'https',
        options: {
          key: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/my_app.key'),
          cert: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/my_app.crt'),
          ca: fs.readFileSync('./ssl/RootCA.pem')
        }
      }
    }
```

To allow the Android Studio emulated devices to open an URL over https using a self signed certificate a script is used to prepare the emulator.

```
export android_emulator_base=~/Library/Android/sdk/emulator
export android_platformtools_base=~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools

# stdout_log <text>
function stdout_log {
  echo $(date +%H:%M:%S) :: $@
}

PS3="Select Android emulator: "

select emulator in $($android_emulator_base/emulator -list-avds | tr '\n' ' '); do
  stdout_log "You selected $emulator"

  stdout_log "Starting emulator"
  $($android_emulator_base/emulator -avd $emulator -writable-system) &
  $android_platformtools_base/adb wait-for-device
  $android_platformtools_base/adb root
  $android_platformtools_base/adb wait-for-device
  stdout_log "Emulator started"

  stdout_log "Remounting emulator"
  wait_for_completion $android_platformtools_base/adb remount
  $android_platformtools_base/adb wait-for-device
  stdout_log "Emulator remounted"

  stdout_log "Pull hosts file"
  $android_platformtools_base/adb pull /system/etc/hosts ~/Downloads/hosts
  $android_platformtools_base/adb wait-for-device
  stdout_log "Hosts file pulled"

  stdout_log "Creating new hosts file"
  echo "127.0.0.1       localhost" >~/Downloads/hosts_new
  echo "::1             ip6-localhost" >>~/Downloads/hosts_new
  echo '10.0.2.2        theme.myapp.nl theme-a.myapp.nl theme-b.myapp.nl' >>~/Downloads/hosts_new

  stdout_log "Uploading new hosts file"
  cat ~/Downloads/hosts_new
  $android_platformtools_base/adb push ~/Downloads/hosts_new /system/etc/hosts
  $android_platformtools_base/adb wait-for-device
  stdout_log "hosts file uploaded"

  stdout_log "Installing CA Certificates"
  $android_platformtools_base/adb shell avbctl disable-verification
  $android_platformtools_base/adb wait-for-device
  hashed_name=$(openssl x509 -inform PEM -subject_hash_old -in ../RootCA.crt | head -1).0
  cp ../RootCA.crt ./$hashed_name
  $android_platformtools_base/adb push $hashed_name /system/etc/security/cacerts
  $android_platformtools_base/adb shell chmod 664 /system/etc/security/cacerts/$hashed_name
  # https://httptoolkit.com/blog/chrome-android-certificate-transparency/
  SKPI_FINGERPRINT=$(openssl x509 -in $hashed_name -pubkey -noout | openssl pkey -pubin -outform der | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64)
  echo "chrome --ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list=$SKPI_FINGERPRINT" >./fingerprint.0
  $android_platformtools_base/adb push fingerprint.0 /data/local/chrome-command-line
  $android_platformtools_base/adb shell chmod 555 /data/local/chrome-command-line/fingerprint.0
  $android_platformtools_base/adb push fingerprint.0 /data/local/android-webview-command-line
  $android_platformtools_base/adb shell chmod 555 /data/local/android-webview-command-linefingerprint.0
  $android_platformtools_base/adb push fingerprint.0 /data/local/webview-command-line
  $android_platformtools_base/adb shell chmod 555 /data/local/webview-command-line/fingerprint.0
  $android_platformtools_base/adb push fingerprint.0 /data/local/content-shell-command-line
  $android_platformtools_base/adb shell chmod 555 /data/local/content-shell-command-line/fingerprint.0
  $android_platformtools_base/adb push fingerprint.0 /data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line
  $android_platformtools_base/adb shell chmod 555 /data/local/tmp/chrome-command-line/fingerprint.0
  $android_platformtools_base/adb push fingerprint.0 /data/local/tmp/android-webview-command-line
  $android_platformtools_base/adb shell chmod 555 /data/local/tmp/android-webview-command-line/fingerprint.0
  $android_platformtools_base/adb push fingerprint.0 /data/local/tmp/webview-command-line
  $android_platformtools_base/adb shell chmod 555 /data/local/tmp/webview-command-line/fingerprint.0
  $android_platformtools_base/adb push fingerprint.0 /data/local/tmp/content-shell-command-line
  $android_platformtools_base/adb shell chmod 555 /data/local/tmp/content-shell-command-line/fingerprint.0

  stdout_log "Rebooting device"
  $android_platformtools_base/adb reboot
  stdout_log "Rebooting initiated, wait till reboot completed"
  $android_platformtools_base/adb wait-for-device
  stdout_log "Rebooting completed"
  break
done
```

for iOS emulators this is less complex

```
xcrun simctl keychain booted add-root-cert ./RootCA.pem
```

This enables me to load de PWA in the browser of the emulated iOS or Android device over HTTPS.

As said, i also use Firebase Functions which are made available in the hosted React application through a Firebase Functions Service.

```
import firebaseConfig from '../firebase-config'
import {connectFunctionsEmulator, httpsCallable} from 'firebase/functions'
import React from 'react'

const functions = firebaseConfig.functions

if (firebaseConfig.useEmulator) {
  connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, 'localhost', 5001)
}

type GetThemeDataReq = {
  themeId: string
}

type GetThemeDataResp = ThemeData

const getThemeData = httpsCallable<GetThemeDataReq, GetThemeDataResp>(
  functions,
  'getThemeData'
)


const retrieveThemeData = (themeId: string) => {
  ....
}

const FirebaseFunctionsService = {
  retrieveThemeData
}
export default FirebaseFunctionsService
```

When opening the app from the emulated device through the URL 'https://theme.myapp.nl' the Firebase function is invoked through 'http://localhost:5001'. This fails because insecure content from the emulated device is blocked.

`[blocked] The page at https://theme.myapp.nl:8800/auth/login was not allowed to display insecure content from http://localhost:5001/mijn-app-1740a/us-central1/getThemeData.`

Running the same PWA in a browser on my desktop, it is able to invoke the Firebase function.

Till now i have not be able to find a way to run firebase functions locally over https, nor to be able to allow my emulated devices to use http instead op https. Setting the Chrome flags #allow-insecure-localhost does not fix the issue.

Also the answers in this question do not resolve the issue because it is not a native Android app.

[How to allow all Network connection types HTTP and HTTPS in Android (9) Pie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie)

I was putting my hope on adding a res/xml/networkSecurityConfig.xml to my emulated Android device using `adb push`, but till now unsuccesfull.

Any ideas how to be access a Firebase Emulated function from an Emulated iOS / Android device over http ?