# RN Android Release build unable to connect to XMPP server

Tags: android, react-native, websocket, xmpp

I have a React Native chat app that connects to an XMPP server hosted on Azure.
The app is using websockets for the connection (`ws://` not `wss://`) with the xmpp.js library.

The app can connect when run locally with a Debug build, but fails to connect when using a Release build.

The same app running on iOS connects with no problems locally or when deployed.

I've tried using the `debug` signing config for `release` and also creating a `release` config with a new keystore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to allow all network connection types in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
</application>
```

For more details, see the top answer from the following post:

[How to allow all Network connection types HTTP and HTTPS in Android (9) Pie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie)