# React Native doesn't work Get request on local network

Tags: react-native, httprequest

I'm new and haven't been able to solve the problem for several days now. There is a device on the local network (smart home) that I can turn on and off from the browser without problems using a get request (http://192.168.0.100/Power?Power=1). I’m writing an application for Android, everything works fine in React Native in the emulator, but after installing the app on a real phone, nothing works anymore. Please help me figure it out.

```
const test = () => {
    fetch('http://192.168.0.100/Power?Power=1', true)
  };
return (
     <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => test()}>
     </TouchableOpacity>
       )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Here is my solution:

To switch a smarthome-device I can send a http-request with any browser:
http://192.168.178.101/relay/0?turn=toggle
But the attempt to write an app with android studio failed.

I tried every library: the old apache, okhttp3, khttp, fuel and volley.

Here a very short code snippet with volley. This works fine with an http-adress in www, but not in my home network:

```
val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this@MainActivity)
url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
val request = StringRequest(
    Request.Method.GET,
    url,
    {
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txtView1).text = it
    },
    { Log.d("error",it.toString())}
)
requestQueue.add(request)
```

I added all thinkable permissions to androidmanifest.xml:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NEARBY_WIFI_DEVICES" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION " />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
```

Astonishing, that the app works on my old smartphone with android 8!

When comparing the Android versions I found this helpful thread:
[How to allow all Network connection types HTTP and HTTPS in Android (9) Pie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie)

After insert this line to androidmanifest.xml it works !!

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

(Alternativ you can downgrade your sdk in gradle to targetSdk = 26, but that is only a emergency solution)

Answer (score 0):

**Answer:**

There are a few possible reasons why your React Native fetch HTTP request might not be working on a real phone

1. Your device might not be connected to the same local network as the smart home device.
2. Your phone might not have the necessary permissions to access the smart home device.
3. There might be a problem with the way that you are making the fetch request.

I think you need to use Axios to make a fetch request the below code is helping you

```
import axios from 'axios';

const test = () => {
  axios.get('http://192.168.0.100/Power?Power=1')
    .then(response => {
      // Success!
    })
    .catch(error => {
      // Error!
    });
};

return (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => test()}>
    <Text>Turn on power</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

And I think you need to check more first

- Make sure that your smart home device is configured to allow remote access.
- If you are using a proxy, make sure that the proxy is configured correctly.

If you are still having trouble, please provide more information about your setup and the error messages that you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!
The phone is connected to the same wifi, everything works fine from the browser on the phone, there is also a MacroDroid application on the phone, I send get from it and also turns everything on and off.
From my application I checked Post and Get requests to external sites go fine, but they don’t want to go to the local area.
I tried axios and fetch, nothing changed.

Comment: Today I tried to connect my phone instead of the Android emulator, the application loaded and everything works well, but when I release the apk and install it on the phone, nothing works again...
I also tried to make an apk through expo, nothing works.

Comment: -> I think that your router is blocking requests from your app. You can try checking the router's settings to see if there is any firewall or other security feature that is blocking requests from your app.

-> Another possibility is that your smart home device is configured to only allow requests from certain IP addresses. You can check the device's settings to see if there is any whitelist or blacklist of IP addresses.

-> I think you can try using a network sniffer to capture the traffic between your phone and the smart home device.