# Why is it that the .NET MAUI WebView is unable to open links to websites which are not safe (SSL certificate untrusted)?

Tags: android, .net, webview, maui

I am trying to access websites via a web viewer that may not have the SSL certificate.
Unfortunately I always get a black screen.

```cs
private async void lwConnections_ItemTapped(object sender, Syncfusion.Maui.ListView.ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    if (lwConnections.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(WebViewer)}?URL={((Connection)lwConnections.SelectedItem).URL}");
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a solution?

I am very new to .NET MAUI and cannot find a solution that I can implement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to allow all Network connection types HTTP and HTTPS in Android (9) Pie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie)

Comment: no unfortunately this has had no effect.