# Exoplayer server videostream

Tags: android, video-streaming, exoplayer2.x

I have a camera device connected as wifi to the phone which can be streamed by vlc or browser, and im making an app to do that there. This code works with mp3 and mp4, but not the http link of the camera. Am I doing something wrong?

strings.xml
media_url_mp3:https://storage.googleapis.com/exoplayer-test-media-0/Jazz_In_Paris.mp3
media_url_mp4:https://storage.googleapis.com/exoplayer-test-media-0/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4
camera_stream:http://192.168.4.1:8081/video

PlayerActivity.kt

```
   private fun initializePlayer(){
        player = SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this)
            .build()
            .also {
                exoPlayer -> viewBinding.videoView.player = exoPlayer
                val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(getString(R.string.camera_stream))
                exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem)

                exoPlayer.playWhenReady = playWhenReady
                exoPlayer.seekTo(currentWindow, playbackPosition)
                exoPlayer.prepare()
            }
    }
```

Maybe the problem is the type, but im confused what should be of the exoplayer options https://developer.android.com/media/media3/exoplayer/dash?hl=pt-br
The stream is a 1280x740 video without audio

Comment: first thought: have you ["allowed" http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie), without S?

Comment: No, is there a simple way to do it?

Comment: well, click the link, you have some answers there