# Android Studio - VideoView only plays videos witth https and not http

Tags: java, android, android-studio, http-live-streaming

I have been working on an android app for live streaming and I used videoview as a player , but it only streams videos with https and throws a message "Can't play this video" if the link starts with http , that only happens on my real device not the emulator , how can I open access for http ? or how can I solve that problem actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the solution actually d this

I have added this code to my Manifest and it worked all well !

`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`

solution taken from [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie)

Answer (score -1):

As you didn't share your code I suppose you used [setVideoURI(Uri uri)] so what I purpose is to use [setOnErrorListener()] and find out the reason the video isn't playing then work on solving it.
check this out :
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnErrorListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener)

and as it works on the emulator the problem could be that the emulator allow http but the phone blocks it for security .
so maybe the following link would be useful:
[Android - Video streaming over local HTTPS server: SSL certificate rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828985/android-video-streaming-over-local-https-server-ssl-certificate-rejected)

Answer (score -1):

Just follow the steps

1) Make xml folder is res then make a xml resource file in xml folder (newtwork_security.xml) then copy the below lines in it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
</base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

2) Go to your manifest file inside application

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/security_config"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


<!--Content-->


</application>
```

give the name of your file in networkSecurityConfig = "Your file"